# Somar valor em um valor de referência determinado a cada dia diferente para todo o ano

Tags: php, data, strtotime, operadores

Como posso somar um determinado valor em um valor existente a cada dia diferente do ano. Algo como:

```
$hoje =  date('Y-m-d');                     
$amanha = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($hoje .' +1 day'));

if ($hoje  != $amanha) {
    somar 40 a 19000
}
//hoje imprime 19040, no dia seguinte imprime 19080 e assim por diante até o fim do ano.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O exemplo abaixo calcula a diferença em dias entre uma data pré-determinada e a data atual, e após isso, faz a soma dos valores como você desejou.

```php
<?php
// Constantes
$DATA_INICIAL = "2019-02-10";
$DATA_ATUAL = time();
$VALOR_INICIAL = 19000;
$VALOR_A_SOMAR = 10;

// Faz a diferença entre as datas desejadas e converte para dias
$diferencaEntreDatasEmMilissegundos = $DATA_ATUAL - strtotime($DATA_INICIAL);
$diferencaEmDias = intval($diferencaEntreDatasEmMilissegundos/86400);

// Efetua a soma desejada
$valorFinal = $VALOR_INICIAL + ($diferencaEmDias * $VALOR_A_SOMAR);
```

Veja funcionando no ideone: https://ideone.com/4qFIiB

Comment: Funcionou bem, apesar de eu ter feito algumas modificações, obrigado João !